# Not able to copy into String array from object

Tags: java

I have a problem in copying the data in array from object variable which is also a type String.

Can any one explain this

```
 String[] childRoot = null;
 int k = 1;
 System.out.println(" Name " + d.getName()); 
 childRoot[k]=d.getName();                         *
 k++;
```

output

```
Name try 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at *
```

Detail for :getName

```
  java.lang.String getName()
  Returns the name of this object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to initialize an array before you can use it. If you don't want to initialize, there's an alternative way you can fill up the array like this:

```
String[] childRoot = {null, d.getName()};
```

I put the first element as null, because you wanted the name to be in index 1 which is the 2nd element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't mark in what line is the exception being raised, is hard to say the problem. There are two points that can raise the exception:

1.- d is not initialized and is NULL

2.- More probably you don't initialized childRoot, you only declare it.

```
final int LENGHT=5;
String[] childRoot = new String[LENGHT];
```